# Matching algorithm for similarities

Tags: algorithm, matching, profile

I'm searching for algorithm, articles, books or whatever, about matching process. So currently I'm writing something like a DatingApp and I calculate a lot of matches.
So I search for an method which solves this issue

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question of [the CS stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51942/is-there-a-name-for-algorithms-which-detect-nearly-similar-structures) and the top answer starts

> The search terms you're probably looking for are "similarity measure", "dissimilarity", "distance function", or "metric"... applied to trees.

Comment: OK. Interesting would be also methods which operates on databases, which are regular not trees ;)

Comment: Yeah - I happened to be interested in trees, but only because you have some trees which share some branches, and other parts which differ. So you get this alike-but-not-the-same property...